# Xcode 5, Export Project to SVN repository

Tags: xcode, xcode5

In previous version of Xcode there was a repository section in Organiser which is now missing in Xcode 5. How to export project to SVN in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One way is using an svn client. The one which is obviously available is the command line svn client. So here's how I use it:

Our repository is: *https://myserver.me.com/svn/*
The repository is added to Xcode using *Xcode->Preferences->Accounts*.

- Create a new project inside Xcode 5: *$HOME/IOS/Projects/MyProject*
- Close the project or maybe even better close Xcode to avoid Xode interfering with svn. Really.
- Open a terminal and change directory into the projects folder

  ```
  cd $HOME/IOS/Projects
  ```
- Import the project into svn:

  ```
  svn import -m "New Import"  MyProject/ https://myserver.me.com/svn/trunk/MyProject
  ```
- Checkout the project again to create a working copy

  ```
  svn co https://myserver/svn/trunk/MyProject MyProject
  ```
- Re-open the project in Xcode and enjoy svn. The project is now part of the repo.

Comment: This has worked for me, but i want a way to do it from Xcode 5.

Comment: But what files to include in the first commit? Can I safely include all project files etc without risking getting problems when my colleague start to work on the project and commit from their machines?

Comment: Just include all the files of the projects first commit. Handling commits from coworkers and handling conflicts is SVN's job. Just seek for any decent SVN manual to learn how this works.

Comment: This is fine but how to do it locally i.e. within Xcode 5 itself.

Answer (score 2):

Select `Source Control ->  Check Out…`
This shows a “Check Out” dialog.

[image: This is Check Out]

Select SVN from **Recents or Repositories** tab.

[image: Check out dialog]

Now, select the directory in which to check out the project.

Click on “Check Out”. This updates the local project to remote SVN.

Answer (score 1):

please refer this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/add_repository.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013306-CH4

and on click on setting btn you can import and export also.

Comment: This only describes how to add repositories, not how to import files into a repository.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 5, you can add/view repositories at Xcode->Preferences->Accounts. You can also view/enter the repository at "Source Control"->"Check Out..."

Comment: That is true, but you cannot add new project to repository using CheckOut command. You can only import existing one.

Comment: This worked pretty well for me... I created an empty folder on SVN; checked it out as @rakmoh suggests; copied the contents of my project into the checked out folder; and now I can easily commit the project using xCode. This is pretty similar in concept to the accepted answer but without using command line