# Using svn in xcode5

Tags: svn, xcode5, svn-merge

I am working on project and now one more team member will be working with me on different module. Can any one guide me how to use svn while working in a team? I need to do following things :

1. Create svn repository of my project.
2. Upload my project to that repository.
3. Commit my project on daily basis and finally and most important
4. Merging of my code with my team member without facing any conflicts.

Please help me and suggest me the best approach to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Start reading [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/index.html):

   - [Chapter 1. Fundamental Concepts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.html),
   - [Chapter 2. Basic Usage](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.html),
   - [Resolve Any Conflicts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve).
2. Add your XCode solution [as described in Xcode docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html) or as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19548640/761095).